# How to put a grid in a drop down menu

Tags: html, grid, drop-down-menu

I have something like a grid of buttons which you can see in the jsfiddle code. What I want though is the grid to be displayed from a drop down menu like in this example [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/colorpicker-controls-for-winforms/ColorPicker.jpg). Does anyone know how to link my grid into a drop down menu like in the example?

code in jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmLmC/13/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pierre/QmLmC/14/).

Added the fake select box.

```
<div class="box">here</div>
```

Added some basic js:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $('table').show();
});

$('table input').click(function(){
    $('.box').html( $(this).clone() );
    $('table').hide();
});
```

And using CSS, hide the table by default:

```
table{display:none}
```

You can add some CSS or JS to dynamically position the table below the fake select.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this example](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/).

The rest is just positioning your grid container with CSS.